# Is a factually incorrect comment "not constructive"?

Tags: discussion, comments

Title of the question says it all really. Does the definition of "not constructive" include comments which are simply factually wrong?

Comment: Might be hard to decide for mods.

Comment: Ideally comments never contain facts.  Not the way they were originally envisioned to be used.  But certainly the way they are now, SO users do about anything to prevent their question from getting closed because the proper answer matches one of the 20 million existing ones.  Making the question intentionally vague is a universal strategy, it forces contributors to post guesses.  You can't be sure it is not a proper guess or won't be useful to the next googler.  That was a guess btw, your question is vague.

Answer (score 15):

No.  It is not up to moderators to judge the factual accuracy of content on the site.  If you feel that a comment is factually inaccurate, you can reply to it to explain why you feel it is wrong.  If the author agrees with your critique, it would then become obsolete, and could merit a moderator deleting it on those grounds.

Answer (score 4):

Let's take one step back here and look at it from *this* angle instead:

Is a comment that isn't asking for clarification into either an OP's question or adding correction to an answer really *constructive*?

Effectively, if you see a comment that states something blatantly wrong, it should tip something off; not because that it was blatantly wrong, but because the comment isn't being used for what it's intended for.  That in my mind merits removal for it being too chatty/not constructive.

As [Servy mentioned prior](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337576/1079354), though, the moderators aren't going to act on content based on it being factually accurate or not, since it's not their primary position to do so.